# Main Menu driven programme for different Projects

Tags: c#

For an assignment i had different DataStructures (in C#) that I needed to implement. That part was easy. But I am also required to make a main menu driven programme for all those projects. So i searched a bit and found out a way. For example i had a project named linkedlist with namespace as Implementing_LinkedList and another project queue and namespace as Implementing_queue. To make a menu driven programme i just created another project named Assignment with namespace assignment. **Mainconsole**. Then i changed the namespace of linkedlist project to Assignment.Implementing_LinkedList and similarly with queue.Also made all the methods and classes public. Then i just called the main method of linkedlist inside main method of assignment as follows

**Implementing_LinkedList.Program.Main();**

Main method is inside a class named program in linked list project and it worked. Now i want to know how this worked because specifically .MainConsole part and if there is any other way to acheive this.

(Also i am pretty new to Stack overflow so pardon me for the extra long question but i didn't want to skip any details)

Comment: i cannot find a problem here.

Comment: Is this a WinForms, Console, WPF or what environment are you making the menu in?

Comment: Making a console application ,i will add the correct code for it the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to rename namespaces or anything. Each program's `Main()` function is static and it can be called from any other function using a *fully qualified name*.

#### Program1.cs

```
namespace Project1
{
    public static class Program1
    {
        public static Main(string[] argc)
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

#### Program2.cs

```
namespace Project2
{
    public static class Program2
    {
        public static Main(string[] argc)
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

#### MenuProgram.cs

```
namespace MenuProject
{
    public static class MenuProgram
    {
        public static Main(string[] argc)
        {
            // call all projects in sequence
            Project1.Program1.Main();
            Project2.Program2.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes the menu project has all the sources of the sub projects included. If they are separate project files, then you need to `Add Reference...` to those projects from the project file references.

Comment: Yes,this works too ,i just had to try it ,And sorry if the question was too hard to understand .